# How to position two tabularray tables side by side in such a way that their top edges align?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularray

**A description of the problem**

I would like to present two tables of different row numbers side by side in such a way that the top edges of the tables' first rows would lie along the same (imaginary) horizontal line.

TeX-wise the two tables are coded as `tblr`s of package `tabularray`.

**An attempt at a solution**

I tried to solve the problem by embedding the two tables as the left and right cells inside another `tblr` table consisting of a single, two column row, and then setting the vertical alignment of the cells of the external table to 't'. As follows.

I saved the following LaTeX code in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{Q[c,t]Q[c,t]}
\begin{tblr}{c}
A
\end{tblr}
&
\begin{tblr}{c}
A\\
B
\end{tblr}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

This resulted in the file `~/Test.pdf` being created. When opened in a PDF viewer the file displayed as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: A table of tables]

As can be seen, this didn't have the desired effect. If the top edges of the first rows of the two inner tables were aligned, then presumably the two letters A would align in such a way that their baselines would be lying on the same (imaginary) horizontal line. But this is not the case. Instead the left `A` is lower on the page than the right `A`.

**Question**

How can two `tblr` tables of different row numbers be positioned side by side on the page in such a way that the top edges of their first rows align along an imaginary horizontal line?

Comment: Why go into all the trouble of nesting tables when you simply could either merge two cells in the left hand column or make a multiline cell at the right?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I could. It's just that logically it's two different tables that I want to show side by side.

Comment: The MWE above is a reduced version of the code I'm dealing with in my real world document. In my document I have two full-blown tables that I want to show side by side, for comparison purposes.

Comment: Then why don't you show your tables side by side instead of putting them in yet another table?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz They have different numbers of rows, and I want their top rows to be vertically aligned. How can I achieve this?

Comment: top aligned minipages

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Can you edit your question to be a representation of your actual problem?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've edited my question per your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `baseline` to top (`T`) to align the tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{cc}
    \begin{tblr}[T]{c}
        A
    \end{tblr}
     &
    \begin{tblr}[T]{c}
        A \\
        B
    \end{tblr}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `T` aligns the first row of the table, whereas `t` aligns the top of the table. For more, see sec. 3.1.6 in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. This is a good answer. Could you please explain why my solution using the `Q[c,t]Q[c,t]` specification for the external table didn't have the desired effect as was achieved with your answer?

Comment: The `t` option here is for vertical alignment of the content of the cells, not of the table itself.

Comment: @EvanAad -- `T` aligns the first row of the table, whereas `t` aligns *only* top of the table, see sec. 3.1.6 in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This answer will address [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671696/how-to-position-two-tabularray-tables-side-by-side-in-such-a-way-that-their-top#comment1669496_671698) of why the attempt shown in the original post of using the specification `Q[c,t]Q[c,t]` failed. The implementation details described below are for explanation purposes only; I have no idea if they reflect the actual implementation of the `tabularray` package.

When a `tblr` has two or more cells in a certain row, these cells can be vertically aligned relative to each other using the vertical alignment specifications `t`, `m`, and `b`. (Also `h` and `f`, but they are mere aliases of `b` and `t`, respectively.)

`tblr` wraps the content of each of the row's cells inside a box, one box per cell. We will refer to these boxes as *alignment boxes*. Each of the alignment boxes has a baseline, and `tblr` aligns these boxes along their baselines.

When the content of one of the cells consists of a single line of text, the vertical alignment specification for this cell is ignored, and the baseline of the alignment box coincides with the single line's baseline.

However, when the content of one of the cells consists of two or more lines of text, the baseline of this cell's alignment box is determined by the vertical alignment specification for this cell (which is `t` by default): If the specification is `t`, the alignment box's baseline is that of the top line; if the specification is `b`, the alignment box's baseline is that of the bottom line; if the specification is `m` and the number of lines is odd, the alignment box's baseline is that of the middle line; and if the specification is `m` and the number of lines is even, the alignment box's baseline is half way between the baselines of the two middle lines.

Each `tblr` has a bounding box with a baseline. By default this baseline is the middle of the `tblr`'s bounding box. The position of this baseline can be specified using `tblr`'s `baseline` option, which can be passed as either an inner specification (i.e. to `tblr`'s mandatory argument) or as an outer specification (i.e. to `tblr`'s optional argument). The possible values of this option are `t`, `T`, `m`, `b`, `B`, and `<n>` for some positive integer `n`. If the value of this option is `t`, the `tblr`'s baseline is the top edge of its bounding box, if the value is `T` it is the baseline of the `tblr`'s first row, if it is `m` it is the vertical middle of the bounding box, if it is `b` it is the bottom edge of the `tblr`'s bounding box, if it is `B` it is the baseline of the `tblr`'s bottom row, and if it is `<n>` it is the baseline of the `tblr`'s `n`th row.

Putting all this information together, when a `tblr` has a row with two or more cells, and the content of one of them is itself a `tblr`, then, regardless of the vertical alignment specification for this cell, the baseline of this cell's alignment box will coincide with the baseline specified (explicitly or by default) for the inner `tblr`, since the content of this cell consists of a single line of text, namely the line comprising a single box: the inner `tblr`'s bounding box. And this line's baseline is therefore the baseline of the inner `tblr`'s bounding box.

Applying this to your example from the original post, each of the external `tblr`'s cells consists of a single line of text comprising the respective inner `tblr`. Therefore, the external `tblr`'s vertical alignment specifications for these cells are ignored, and the baselines of the two cells' alignment boxes are set to coincide with those of these lines, respectively. These baselines, in turn, coincide with the baselines of the respective inner `tblr`'s bounding boxes. Since no baselines have been specified for the two inner `tblr`s explicitly, their baselines are set by default to `m`, i.e. their baselines are at the vertical middles of their respective bounding boxes. Therefore, the two tables are vertically aligned along their respective vertical middles.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The documentation for this section of the package is quite difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

There are situations, I would explicitly set the `baseline` of each sub-table to say row 1 and apply an inner alignment across such headers. For instance the table below contain headers with multiple lines of different size, while `Q[c,b]` aligns tables w.r.t to a bottom line of each header.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{c}
  \begin{tblr}{
      baseline=1,
      colspec={Q[c,b]},
      hline{2},
    }
    {Header Line 1\\Header Line 2\\Header Line 3} \\
    Line 1 \\
    Line 2
  \end{tblr}
  &
  \begin{tblr}{
      baseline=1,
      colspec={Q[c,b]},
      hline{2},
    }
    {Header Line 1\\Header Line 2} \\
    Line 1 \\
    Line 2 \\
    Line 3
  \end{tblr}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think your post answers either my original question, or the one in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671696/how-to-position-two-tabularray-tables-side-by-side-in-such-a-way-that-their-top/671730#comment1669496_671698). However, you gave a nice example to put to the test the theory expounded in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671730/21685). And the theory passes this test.